# Silverlight Cross-Domain Calls without WCF

Tags: silverlight, wcf, cross-domain

I have a Silverlight application.  I'm trying to make calls to RESTful web service.

The internet seems to say I need to make WCF proxy, and put the Silverlight client access policy file in the root of that WCF proxy.

My question is --
Can I just put a client access policy file on the root of the RESTful (non-WCF) webservice, and forget about the WCF middle man?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely.  Rather than making your calls through a WCF proxy, you'll just make your calls through the standard WebClient.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Is there any reason i shouldn't do this directly?  Once I have the basic calls working, I will configure SSL.  With SSL, I feel like communications between my silverlight app and the RESTful web server will be secure.

Comment: @Kyle - There's a lot of reasons why you might not want to use REST services exclusively, but if you're trying to access one that already exists and you have your security concerns taken care of to your satisfaction, there's no real reason not to.  Most of the advice you'll read out there either assumes you either don't have access to the service's root (in order to put in the client access policy file) or that you're starting from scratch and using the WCF stack (because you want something different than you can get from a REST service).  Sounds like you know what you want though.  Good luck!